# In App for Two Non Consumable products in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

I am making a game in Sprite Kit.

I have IAPProducts Swift File with code:

```
import Foundation

enum IAPProducts: String {

    case nonConsumable1 = "Kingdom.Lion"
    case nonConsumable2 = "Kingdom.Sheep"
}
```

and IAPService.Swift file with code:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

var lionpurchased = false
var sheeppurchased = false

class IAPService: NSObject {

    private override init() {}
    static let shared = IAPService()

    var products = [SKProduct]()
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

    func getProducts() {
        let products: Set = [
                            IAPProducts.nonConsumable1.rawValue,
                            IAPProducts.nonConsumable2.rawValue
                             ]



        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        paymentQueue.add(self)
    }

    func purchase(product: IAPProducts) {
        guard let productToPurchase = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue }).first else { return }
        let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)

        paymentQueue.add(payment)
    }

    func restorePurchases() {
        print("restore purchases")
        paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

}

extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        products = response.products
        for product in response.products {
            print(product.localizedTitle)

        }
    }
}


extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)

            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing: break
            default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SKPaymentTransactionState {
    func status() -> String {
        switch self {


        case .deferred: return "deferred"
        case .failed: return "failed"
        case .purchased:
              return "purchased"

        case .purchasing: return "purchasing"
        case .restored: return "restored"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I need to know which NonConsumable Product was purchased? I need to know what should I check is equal to  IAPProducts.nonConsumable1.rawValue and  IAPProducts.nonConsumable2.rawValue

Comment: `SKProductTransaction` has `payment`. `SKPayment` has `productIdentifier`.

Comment: Hi rmaddy, thanks for your response but what do I write to check and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` method you need to check the state of each transaction. If the state is `.purchased`, then look at the transaction's payment. The payment's `productIdentifier` tells you which in-app purchase was purchased.

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        if transaction.state == .purchased {
            let productId = transaction.payment.productIdentifier
            // Your code to handle the completed purchase of this IAP
        }

        queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to this and not sure what to write. Should I write: case.purchased: return paymentQueue.productidentifier in paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:). I am getting an error when I write this